# Stackoverflow's use of localstorage for Authorization seems unsafe. Is this correct else how do we strengthen it?

Tags: javascript, html, authorization, local-storage, single-sign-on

I have been working on a Authentication and authorization module similar to how stackexchange is in place. Now I am sure they use a certain model of oAuth or a token generation server that authorizes uses to their various sites. I tried a little experiment.

Once I am logged into Stackoverflow, I delete all my cookies from the developer console.

I leave my localstorage object intact which contains a key `se:fkey xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` for stackoverflow domain.

there is another key for stackauth domain `GlobalLogin: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

the se.fkey if I used for a session hijack, nothing happened. but the GlobalLogin, I was able to copy and hijack my session. So, my query would be, how does S/O deal with the authorization post authentication for each one of the sites. Also, is there a way to invalidate the globalLogin for them after it is used once?

**{EDIT1}**

So, just the `globalLogin` alone is enough. If you can get that key, just open a private browsing instance. In the Localstorage for stackauth when you are in the login page, create the `key-value` mapping and refresh the page.  You will be logged in.

**{EDIT2}**

The `globalLogin` key seems to be consistent across multiple sessions. It has been a day and no refresh of my `globalLogin` key. Safe to assume if you key is hijacked, the attacker will have access to your profile indefinitely.

**{EDIT3}**

For everyone who is voting and will vote for this question as not a programming related question. Let me put it this way, how do we store SSO's on the web browser with localstorage safely and since they are prone to get compromised, what do we need to do prevent it from happening? One of my colleagues was considerate enough to give me his GlobalLogin key, I was able to hijack his session from a different computer albeit it was on the same network.

[image: Set the GlobalLogin key life this]

PS: This is purely for theoretical understanding that I did this.

Comment: I have tried what you have suggested on my system, this looks like a Joke, it is so simple.

It is not a secure implementation by any means, all that you need a compromised system for 5 minutes, copy GlobalLogin key which remains same for a given user and then keep login using that individual's GlobalLogin at will from any system using incognito browsing

Stack overflow beware this is dangerous, will surely lead to compromising user profiles by fraudulent elements

Comment: I can't see GlobalLogin key. Is it under stackoverflow domain? and Which login method(s) are you using?

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze you will find it in the [stackauth.com](https://stackauth.com/) domain. In the localstorage. Use chrome inspector and copy the globalLogin. Then fill this, it's very straightforward!

Comment: I did it but I'm not logged in. I tried different browser and incognito tab. I'm using this in console: localStorage.setItem('GlobalLogin', 'xxxxxxxx'); am I messed something?

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze yep, your key will get set on the instance of stackoverflow and not stackauth. Simply use the grid to do this. I will post a picture, give me a minute.

Comment: i dont see the problem unless you have a habit of publishing your tokens...

Comment: @dandavis like I said, it's not as much as you yourself doing this. More like someone else grabs them from your device. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Shouvik: chrome usually stores the password anyway. stealing (or borrowing) a device is a known vector, but that's not stack's problem, or a flaw in their system. the domain in question is https, so a physical compromise is the only known way that this could pose a problem.

Comment: that said, after i imported my chrome cookies into the new firefox dev edition, i'm stuck in a login redirect infinite loop. i wish there was a prominent logout button for the concerned and non-webdev users out there...

Comment: @dandavis Agreed physical compromise will pose a problem, but also the fact that the GlobalLogin key doesn't change over extended periods of time, and can be used for infinite access should be a cause for concern. Also if I were to leverage this model of authorization for a enterprise framework, where everyone has access to other people's system, pretty sure this would not be acceptable. The concept is novel, just looking to figure how it can be made fool proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64865/discussion-between-shouvik-and-dandavis).

Comment: Your work about might not be a best practice, imagine your end user is browsing over an unsecured connection or in cafe, the user session can easily be hijacked. Make sure you use strict https for all your pages. .htaccess should help with that

Comment: Any idea why I am not seeing second local storage entry for stackauth.com in my chrome debugger tools? Is this changed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, rather than looking at the vulnerability, let's look at the possible attack vectors. I'll add a table here as a TL/DR

```
Attacker      | Vulnerable?
Eavesdropper  | Yes
MITM          | Yes
Local Attack  | Yes
Server Attack | Yes
```

So yes, it is an issue.

### Remote Attacker, can observe traffic, but cannot modify traffic

Consider this a passive attacker in a coffee shop. They can see all of the TCP level traffic.

The requests back and forth to SO are -by-default- not encrypted. You can browse via HTTPS, but by default it's HTTP only.

So an attacker can see any request go by, and inspect/steal the data.

So let's see if the `GlobalLogin` token is ever sent in a request...

As a matter of fact, it is. On the login page, a request is sent via an iframe to the following URL:

```
https://stackauth.com/auth/global/read?request=//snip//
```

That URL returns a script:

```
var data = {
    "ReadSession":"https://stackauth.com/auth/global/read-session",      
    "Request":"//snip//",
    "Nonce":"//snip//",
    "Referrer":"//snip//",
    "StorageName":"GlobalLogin"
};

var toMsg = window.parent;
var obj = localStorage.getItem(data.StorageName);

if(obj != null) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open(
        'POST', 
            data.ReadSession+
            'request='+encodeURIComponent(data.Request)+
            '&nonce='+encodeURIComponent(data.Nonce)+
            '&seriesAndToken='+encodeURIComponent(obj), 
        false
    );
    req.send(null);

    if(req.status == 200){
        toMsg.postMessage(req.responseText, data.Referrer);
    }else{
        toMsg.postMessage('No Session', data.Referrer);
    }
}else{
    toMsg.postMessage('No Local Storage', data.Referrer);
}
```

Now, notice that the `GlobalLogin` is sent over HTTPS to the server. So a remote attacker, who can read traffic will not be able to get the `GlobalLogin` token.

So the `GlobalLogin` portion is safe from eavesdroppers.

However, note that it's still quite vulnerable to sniffing the session cookie, since it's sent over HTTP.

### Remote Attacker, can modify traffic (MITM)

Well, here's where things get interesting.

If you can modify traffic, you can do something really fun.

The initial page creates an iframe bringing in the above stackauth.com URL via HTTPS. Well, if you can modify the initial page (also possible via XSS), you can downgrade the request to HTTP.

And StackAuth.com will be just fine with that. When it makes the request to stackauth.com, you would need to intercept that as well, and change its `ReadSession` URL to be HTTP as well.

But then, all you need to do is watch the call to the `ReadSession` URL, and boom, you've stolen the `GlobalLogin` token.

But the traffic is HTTP anyway, so it doesn't matter since you don't need to go through that trouble to steal the cookie. So why bother?

### Local Attacker

If the person has access to the computer to read the local storage file, they can do **FAR** worse than just steal your login token.

There's a class of attack called "Browser In The Middle", where a compromise in the browser allows an attacker to do whatever they want.

And there's no real effective protection against it other than to try to keep the browser secure (there's nothing you can do from your end).

So if an attacker can get local access to the computer, it's game over.

### Server-Based Attacker

If an attacker can get access to StackOverflow's servers, it's game over anyway...

### Conclusion

As long as HTTP is allowed (since a MITM can always downgrade the connection to HTTP), there's nothing to protect as session secrets always be stealable via eavesdropping.

The only way of protecting this information is to use [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) and force HTTPS everywhere.

It's worth noting that you could protect `GlobalLogin` by forcing HSTS on stackauth.com, leaving the main site accessible over HTTP. This wouldn't prevent the effect of the attack (session hijacking). But it would protect the one vector.

But going HTTPS only via HSTS everywhere would be the best and really only way to prevent these kinds of problems. Anything else would be a bandaid on a gunshot wound.

*Note:* I did talk to SO about this prior to posting this.

Comment: From what I understand, the most major issue is from machine compromise and since the `GlobalLogin` never expires, they pretty much doom the user if stolen. The other attack vectors require compromises on multiple levels. I suppose the easiest way to secure a possibly vulnerable `GlobalLogin` is to to tie the login to a users storage instance. Every new login generates a new `GlobalLogin`. This way if a user logs out of his machine, he will effectively terminate all the "stolen" sessions.

Comment: Have you verified that the token is the same across machines?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. I have explained how the hack was carried out. The token doesn't change even if you log out and log in again.

Comment: Have you heard back from SO on this implementation? What is their opinion?