# How to secure server API in order to reject fake-client calls?

Tags: security, server, token

I'm developing both server and client side of a web application and it is almost finish. Now, it is time to secure it.

I read lots of articles and Q-A sites to understand the principles of the concept. But there are still question marks on my mind.

There is a similar question here:
[How do I secure REST API calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895679/how-do-i-secure-rest-api-calls)

They suggested to use token-based security system, which is very common and practical way. Also services like Firebase, Auth0 are providing this security system.

And this is about "how and where to store token": https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens

If so, how can token protect server from fake-calls while we are storing it in the browsers local storage?

Explaining it with an example in order to be clear:
My client-side code has a form with options. One of the option can be selected via drop down option and there are only "1,2,3,4" in those options. So that, client can never send a form with "5" value to the server. But what if someone use a API tool (for example postman) to send a form with a value of 5? Attacker still can add a token to that request. First login to system as normal user. Than open the developer console of the browser, copy your token and paste to the header of your fake-request.

Not allowing the cross origin calls may solve the problem. But I am not sure if this means server and client should run on the same domain (or host)?

Bonus from stackoverflow: [Stackoverflow's use of localstorage for Authorization seems unsafe. Is this correct else how do we strengthen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26891083/stackoverflows-use-of-localstorage-for-authorization-seems-unsafe-is-this-corr)

They are also discussing the similar question from another aspect. (Not for the server security but for the user's security.)

Not related but in case of need: front-end is developed with Angular 5, server is developed with Java and Spring Framework.

Comment: You have many problems to consider, not just authentication. Look into API gateways e.g. Apigeee, WSO2, Mulesoft

Comment: "Now, it is time to secure it." - Bad news, now it is way too late to secure it.

Comment: @DavidBrossard thanks for the keywords. I'm reading about them.

Comment: @GaborLengyel I'm still student and have much time to do again and again and again... Learning is the key point here no matter what it costs. I need links to read instead of bad news :)